# Hibernate Envers L2 caching

Tags: java, hibernate, hazelcast, hibernate-envers

I cannot find any straight up solution for this so I rather ask also for the future reference:

How do I cache calls to Hibernate's Envers AuditReader?

I have configured Hazelcast as L2 cache provider for Hibernate across my project and now, I can see mostly Envers calls being executed on the database in the Postgresql log.

This is my class that provides some (for me) useful revision details for an entities:

```
@Service
public class RevisionProvider {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PersistenceContext(name = Vedantas.PU_NAME, type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private AuditReader auditReader;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public OperationCtx getCreationRevisionFor(Class aClass, long id) {
        auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);

        log.info(new LogModel("getting creation revision for entity class: {}; id: {}").toString(), aClass.getName(), id);

        final Object[] array = (Object[]) auditReader.createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(aClass, false, false)
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionType().eq(RevisionType.ADD))
                .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id))
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .getSingleResult();

        return ((OperationCtx) array[1]);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public OperationCtx getLastRevisionFor(Class aClass, long id) {

        log.info(new LogModel("getting last revision for entity class: {}; id: {}").toString(), aClass.getName(), id);

        auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
        final Object[] array = (Object[]) auditReader.createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(aClass, false, false)
                .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id))
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().maximize()
                        .computeAggregationInInstanceContext()
                )
                .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc())
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .getSingleResult();

        OperationCtx lastchg = (OperationCtx) array[1];
        OperationCtx creation = getCreationRevisionFor(aClass, id);

        if (creation.getId() == lastchg.getId())
            return new OperationCtx();

        return lastchg;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List getHistoryFor(Class aClass, String pk, String val) {

        log.info(new LogModel("getting history for entity class: {}; on primaryKey: {}, with value: {}").toString(), aClass.getName(), pk, val);

        auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
        List res = auditReader.createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(aClass, false, false)
                .add(AuditEntity.property(pk).eq(val))
                .getResultList();

        return res;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void setManipulationCtx(FindDTO dto, long id) {
        OperationCtx cctx = getCreationRevisionFor(DocVersion.class, id);
        OperationCtx lctx = getLastRevisionFor(Metadata.class, dto.metadata.getId());


        dto.createCtx = cctx;

        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(lctx.getUserId()))
            lctx = cctx;

        dto.lastChangeCtx = lctx;
    }
}
```

Mostly I call `setManipulationCtx` for some DTO object to get creation and last change revision. Creation revision won't change in time. Last change cached revision could be cached and evicted when there is some change on the entity.

So I think I need some way to manually put the object into the cache first time and then query the cache firstly on subsequent calls.

How do I do that?

Hibernate: 5.2.9.Final;

Envers: 5.2.12.Final;

Hazelcast: 3.10.1;

Thanks for tips!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Envers doesn't really expose a way to interact and use the 2LC; however I could see that being a useful feature to add.  I've added [HHH-12652](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12652) as a follow-up.